# Angle between two planes in $n$-dimensional space, where $n \geq 4$

Tags: vector-spaces, vectors, normed-spaces, orthogonality, angle

As known, an angle between two planes in $3$d is an angle between normals to them. But how about $n$-dimensional spaces, $n\geq4$. Is it the same for them? Why is it so?

I have two planes, given parametric in a $4$D Euclidean space (
$U: a_{0}+a_{1}t_{1}+a_{2}t_{2}$ and V: $b_{0}+b_{1}t_{1}+b_{2}t_{2}$, where $a_{i}$, $b_{i}$ are given $4$D vectors) and I need to find an angle between these planes.

I think that the task need to be done the following way:

1. ortogonalise $a_{i}$ in U and $b_{i}$ in V
2. take a random vector that is not in U or V and find normals to every plane
3. find an angle between these two normals using a formula: $\dfrac{(n_{u}, n_{v})}{||n_{u}||||n_{v}||}$,

Is it right?. In my class textbooks or via Internet I could not find anything relevant to such a case.

Comment: How do you define an angle in 4D ?

Comment: This is a bit confusing, as there is not a "normal" vector to the plane, but rather a "normal 2-dimensional plane". For the question to make sense, you should first define what is a angle of two planes. Maybe minimal possible angle between two lines in those planes?

Comment: Is there any formal definition of what an angle in 4D is? I couldn't find any and I don't understand how to define it myself.

Comment: You have a formula for the cosine of the angle between two vectors. It works in any number of dimensions. In $N$ dimensions, the angle between $(N-1)$-dimensional hyperplanes is the angle between their normal vectors. But I'm curious about why you need to find an angle between two two-dimensional planes in a four-dimensional space.

Answer (score 1):

There is, in general, not a single angle between planes, but two. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angles_between_flats

For two flats ($m$-dimensional subspaces) in an $N$-dimensional space ($N\ge m$), one can define $m$ angles between them. At most $\max(m,N-m)$ of them are non-zero. So, for two planes ($m=2$), there are two angles, at most $N-2$ non-zero. In our common 3-dimensional space ($N=3$), at least one of the angles is zero, and everything can be determined by a single (possibly zero too) angle.

In a 4-dimensional space, the two angles can be non-zero, so you need both of them.

You can define a "pseudo-angle" $\Phi$, with:

\begin{equation}
\cos\Phi = \prod_{i=1}^m \cos\phi_i
\end{equation}

where $\phi_i$ are the individual $m$ angles. In 3 dimensions, again, one of the angles is zero and its cosine is 1, so trivially $\Phi$ reduces to the common angle between planes. In more dimensions it is still true that for $\cos\Phi=1$ the planes are parallel and for $\cos\Phi=0$ they are orthogonal.